# Error while checking the Retention Policy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, 2019, information-management, classic-experience

I have a Sharepoint 2019 on-premise site collection in the Classic experience UI. We use library level "Information Management Policy" (check the section [3. HOW TO SET RETENTION POLICY FOR THE DOCUMENT LIBRARY](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/))  but it return below error message:

```
"Cannot check retention policy on this site" Error in "https://SC/Site/ _layouts/15/policycts.aspx?List={ListID}"
```

This is what I have checked :

1. Turn off "Library and Folder Based Retention" site collection feature

This is what I believe need to check but I don't have access.

1. [SharePoint server timer job](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/default-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-server-2019) , "Information management policy"

What else do I need to check to make sure I can solve "Cannot check retention policy on this site" error in the library setting level ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, this notification is harmless and can be ignored. Generally, the timer job will be executed on weekly basis. Your retention policy will still be applied to the library and work normally after then.